# New line in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, newline

I am getting records from database as comma separated. I am getting contact
titles as:

```
greg w.workcerf, ashir ali, asdddfgjk
```

This is comma separated has been defined in SQL function `getCommaListTitle()`

What i want  is to get these record on new lines as

```
greg w.workcerf,
ashir ali,
asdddfgjk
```

Any idea about what should i use in sql function instead of `','`

Comment: `getCommaListTitle` isn't a standard function - we might have to see its definition in order to help you.

Comment: Perform that on data access layer, not data layer itself.

Comment: What framework do you use to access your database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this in your front end, like on data access layer or may be at presentation layer because your application could be any one a web app or a window app and in both there's different in new line syntax like in web we use `<br/>` tag whereas in window we use `/n`.

Answer (score 48):

Append after the comma in `getCommaListTitle`,  `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` for a
new line

`CHAR(13)` is a new line char and `CHAR(10)` is a line feed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx

Answer (score 3):

use the `replace` function

```
replace(field, ',', ',' + char(13)+char(10)
```

...however DO NOT do this in your database, database is about DATA and of course it 'should' be presented in some form... but starting with a line break, and finally you'll end with something like:

```
SELECT @s = '<tr><td>' + firstname + '</td><td>' + substr(lastname, 1, 30) + '</td></tr>'
FROM ....

RETURN '<table>' + @s + '</TABLE>'
```

and that is not to route to choose grasshopper